# Android, sharing goes straight to Gmail, skip other apps

Tags: android, android-intent

I implement a sharing menu item and start the Chooser intent manually (instead of using ShareActionProvider).

My code:

```
case R.id.share_a_query:
    {

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.i("Share menu click", "Tung");

        try{
            Intent intentPartager = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intentPartager.setType("text/*");
            intentPartager.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "plain text text")         ;
            Intent startingIntent = Intent.createChooser(intentPartager, "Share this using...");
            startActivity(startingIntent);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            //Toast.makeText(this, R.string.erreurFaceBookAbsent, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        return true;
    }
```

If I set the type as `text/plain` or `text/*`, the app doesn't show the chooser at all, but instead jump directly to Gmail. If I change that to `image/*` then a list of apps is shown. Am I missing anything here? Tks

Comment: On Android KitKat (4.4)?

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that, but yes!

Comment: There is a bug on Android in this Version. Try it with a lower level.

Comment: @TungMaiLe It is based on the apps installed on your device, if they specify `text/plain` or `text/*` in their manifest then only the chooser will show the specific app. In your case only Gmail app supporting above formats hence it is directly launched

Comment: @Pragnani but there is plenty of apps supporting text/plain like Evernote, (native) Note (on Nexus 7), so Gmail is not the only one that should catch that intent.

Comment: Also @kai said it might be a bug.. try with a lower version of android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the link. I dont know when it get fixed.

http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/11/26/bug-watch-kitkats-share-dialog-can-forget-to-give-you-a-choice-of-apps-to-share-to-set-your-last-used-app-as-the-default/

Comment: So it is definitely a bug

Comment: @Vishal Vyas why that? :D

Comment: @kai I was trying to share apps using Play Store and by default it was  sharing with Gmail app only. I was very frustrated and was about to flash my Nexus 4 back to Jelly beans but I found this post and your reference to blog on androidpolice saved my life ;)